# Django-administration css file not rendered

Tags: python, css, django, django-admin

I am using django administration for basic CRUD . My admin template loads easily , even css files are loaded but it is showing no effect at all.

I tried to collect static files as below

```
Manage.py collectstaic
```

It shows following errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\hello\manage.py", line 10, in
module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
76, in load_command_class
    return module.Command()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\com
ands\collectstatic.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.storage.path('')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", l
ne 46, in path
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app w
thout having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
```

How to solve ut?

Comment: set STATIC_ROOT in settings.py ?  django have to know where u would like to collect static files

Answer (score 0):

include your `STATIC_ROOT`, eg.

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles' 
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
STATICFILES_DIRS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'static')
```

and then include it corresponding url in the `urls.py` file eg.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', ) +static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

remember to put

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

in your `urls.py`

then in your terminal type `python manage.py collectstatic` not collectstaic